# Windows 7: Change the priority of traffic to wired instead of the wireless connection?

Tags: networking, powershell, tcp, metric

On Windows 7 clients I have to change the metric of the wired network connection to a lower metric than the wireless so traffic is prioritized over the wired connection.  Is there a way to do this through a script using powershell?

To do this manually i -> Open network and sharing centre -> click the network wired connection -> select properties -> IPv4 -> advanced -> disable automatic metric -> enter a interface of 10 and then repeat for the wireless network adapter but enter a higher metric of say 20.

I've found these instruction on how to get the metric through netstat but not how to change the metric.   Thank.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Try the WMI SetIPConnectionMetric method:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393303(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)